# sql including null values in transform statement ms-access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need help including null values in my query. Let's say I have this table:

```
 table1:

| in/out | year   | name |
|   in   | 2011-12| jim
|   in   | 2011-12| tim
|   in   | 2012-13| toby
|   out  | 2011-12| ron
|   out  |2012-13 | jim
|   out  |2012-13 | joel
```

I created this transform statement:

```
Transform Count(*)
SELECT [in/out] FROM table1 WHERE name = "jim" GROUP BY [in/out]
PIVOT year IN("2011-12", "2012-13");
```

To get this table:

```
|in/out| 2011-12 | 2012-13 
|  in  |   1     |   1
```

The thing is I want to include all in/out values even if they are null so for this example I'd want the table to look like this:

```
|in/out| 2011-12 | 2012-13 
|  in  |   1     |   1
| out  |         |
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I just replicated the scenario exactly like yours and I dont get either of your results. i get [in-1-NULL] and [out-NULL-1]

Comment: however, access changed the statement slightly to this: TRANSFORM Count(*) AS Expr1
SELECT table1.inout
FROM table1
WHERE (((table1.[name])="jim"))
GROUP BY inout
PIVOT table1.Year In ("2011-12", "2012-13");

Comment: @braX Maybe it's me that's messing up...I don't have my work with me but regardless, do you know of a way I can get what I want?